# Browsing to file on IIS website produces HTTP 404: Not Found from IE

Tags: internet-explorer, iis, http-status-code-404

I added a .xml file to a virtual directory of one of our Sharepoint dev sites. The file can't be found by my browser. Navigating to `http://portaldev/clientaccesspolicy.xml` produces a **HTTP 404: Not Found - "Webpage cannot be found" error in IE11.** I've tried putting this same file in a subfolder with no difference (i.e. /test/client...xml). Navigating to `http://portaldev` opens the Sharepoint landing page correctly. The original problem I was having was similar to [this one](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/85b4b91e-7aa6-4f7b-82ed-8ecf30e9bfef/error-attempting-to-access-a-service-in-a-crossdomain-way-without-a-proper-crossdomain-policy-in?forum=silverlightweb); by running Fiddler when receiving that error I found that my application is looking for the clientaccesspolicy.xml file above, but can't find it - 404 Not Found.

Unfortunately this is not an IIS error so I have no way to log it. Checked the IIS logs anyway but there are no new logs or changes to logs. No event viewer errors either. The website is correctly mapped to the virtual directory, or at least I think it is. When I right click -> Explore it takes me to the virtual directory, and in the root folder of that directory I have the XML file. I've also tried creating or adding new images and text files which produced the same error; although, **navigating to existing images in the vdir worked fine**.

Additionally, I have tried an IISReset, restarting the specific website, and recycling the app pool that the site is using. My firewall is completely off and "Everyone" has full permission to the virtual directory. I have IE11. I've tried it in Chrome, which either provides "HTTP 404 NOT FOUND" or a blank page. Can anyone recommend a page where I can troubleshoot this type of issue, or give advice? I tried searching for it, but since it's an IE error most of the people aren't talking IIS web apps.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On our domain we have two servers for Sharepoint development: a general app/dev server and a web front-end server (WFE). I had tried all of the above on the app/dev server, not on the WFE. When **I recycled the app pool on the WFE**, I was able to access the XML file from both servers. As a result, the application validated the access policy file and is now working. HTH.